# Is there a name for a graph in which every vertex is both a central vertex and a peripheral vertex

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, rubiks-cube

Is there a name for a graph for which every vertex
is simultaneously in the center and in the periphery of the graph?

If I'm not mistaken the graph representing the states of the Rubik's cube
whose edges are the twists of the cube is such a graph.  I.e., for such a graph there is no *special* state.    I suppose the complete graph $K_n$ is such a graph as well.

Comment: Kind of a non-answer, but I think there isn't a name for it :/ -- tag me if you get a positive answer, though, as I'd be interested to know! `:-)`

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by a vertex being in the centre or the periphery. How do you determine that? Would that not depend on how you draw the graph? Maybe the property you are looking for is vertex-transitive, where every vertex essentially looks the same, cause the symmetries of the graph can map any vertex to any other. If the vertices were unlabelled, you could not distinguish one from another in a vertex-transitive graph. The Rubik's Cube graph is the Cayley graph of a group, and those are always vertex-transitive.

Comment: Sorry if my question was confusing: By center or periphery, I don't mean anything about the drawing.  By center I mean the set of points with minimum eccentricity.  And by periphery I mean the set of points with maximum eccentricity.  I was just looking for the name of a graph with homogeneous eccentricity.

Comment: Thanks, I was not familiar with centre/periphery in the graph theory context.

Answer (score 4):

Such a graph is called a [self-centered graph](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32301/examples-of-self-centered-graphs-with-large-radius).

This is defined in the linked post as a graph whose diameter equals its radius; therefore the maximum eccentricity of any vertex equals the minimum eccentricity.

Note that the Rubik's cube graph has a much stronger property. It is vertex-transitive: there is an automorphism that maps any vertex to any other vertex. In a sense, no graph property can distinguish a vertex from any other. A self-centered graph is one where vertices cannot be distinguished *by eccentricity alone*, but there might still be other distinguishing characteristics.